# How to execute a Javascript function after another has completed using promises?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I wish to refresh the page after values have been saved to a database, using js promises.

My code is wrapped inside a jQuery event listener:

```
$("img[class=okButton]").click(function(){
  var field_userid = $(this).attr("id");

  doThisFirst();

  // then make a promise
  const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  wait(500).then(() => writeNewRoom(field_userid)); // function to write to database

  refreshPage(); // after write has finished
});

///////////////////

function writeNewRoom(field_userid)){
// ajax to do something;
}

///////////////////

function refreshPage(){
if(window.confirm("Click to refresh")){location = location}
}
```

The intended behaviour is to process data first, then finish "doing something" in the writeNewRoom() function before refreshing the page in the refreshPage() function.

What is actually happening is that the first doThisFirst() function is processed correctly, but then the window.confirm box in the third function, pops up BEFORE the writeNewRoom function has run.

I've never used promises before, so can anyone help figure out what went wrong?  I took the basic syntax from the mozilla website: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do it inside a `.then` callback?

Comment: Would [promise chaining](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining#returning-promises) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you would want to put a call back in your `writeNewRoom()` method.

For example, you call whatever you need to do on the `.click()` function and put a `.done()` method when your ajax call for writing to the database is done.

```
$("img[class=okButton]").click(function(){
    var field_userid = $(this).attr("id");

    doThisFirst();

    // Remove the Promise
    writeNewRoom(field_userid); // function to write to database
});

function writeNewRoom(field_userId) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/someurl",
        method: "method",
        data: { 
          a: field_userId
       }
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log('success', data) 
        refreshPage(); // This is where you refresh the page. 
    }).fail(function(xhr) {
        console.log('error', xhr);
    });
}
```

Comment: Because `writeNewRoom` will be probably async because of ajax.

Comment: @floriangosse Didn't notice `writeNewRoom()` was async. Fixed it

Comment: Thanks JustinJmnz, this did the trick, although I used the jQuery '$.post()' function in place of '$.ajax()'.  It occurs to me that the promise didn't work as expected... in fact triggering the reload from the post result probably means I don't need the promise at all to get the required behaviour.

Comment: @Helang_IT You are correct in not needing the first `Promise()`

Answer (score -1):

If your `// ajax to do something;` returns a promise (jQuery.ajax() does) you can do it like this:

```
wait(500).then(() => writeNewRoom(field_userid))
         .then(() => refreshPage());
```

There's also one extra parenthesis here `function writeNewRoom(field_userid))`

Comment: Thanks.  I did try this but unfortunately it doesn't work.  Same behaviour as before.

Answer (score -1):

if the `writeNewRoom(field_userid)` is doing an ajax call, you put the `refreshPage()`-function into the callback of the ajax call, so it is executed AFTER the ajax has finished, e.g:

```
function writeNewRoom(field_userid)){

   $.ajax({
       url: "someUrl",
       type: 'GET',
       success: (result) => { 
          refreshPage()    //when ajax has succeded, refresh page
       },
       error: (err) => {
        //do something else

       }
   });

}
```